# how to use http(httpie) command to Repeat URL Request?

Tags: bash, http

how do we repeat the below command to fire **100**'s of same request on my bash terminal?

```
http GET welcomer.loreans.com/welcome
```

http is from `httpie`(https://httpie.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Another version of your linear solution:

```sh
for i in `seq 1 100`; do http GET welcomer.loreans.com/welcome; done
```

As far as URL Requests are concerned, [`GNU Parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) is more suitable for your task.

Straight from the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html):

> GNU parallel is a shell tool for executing jobs in parallel using one or more computers. The typical input is a list of files, a list of hosts, a list of users, a list of URLs, or a list of tables.

So if you want the request to originate from different computers, you can adapt the following command which uses only one computer.

```sh
parallel http GET welcomer.loreans.com/welcome ::: `seq 1 100`
```

Unlike the ampersand solution, this will not bring your laptop to its knees if you increase drastically the number of requests you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
repeat 100 http GET welcomer.loreans.com/welcome
```

Comment: Show output of `type repeat`.

Comment: The repeat command simply repeats n number of times
` repeat 2 echo "hello" ` will print hello twice

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little bit of a twist on this task.  Here's code to run that query 100 times in parallel:

```
seq 1 100 | xargs -I% -P100 http GET welcomer.loreans.com/welcome
```

And here's similar code to run the tasks parallel, but without xargs:

```
for i in $(seq 1 100)
do
  http GET welcomer.loreans.com/welcome &
done
wait
```

As you can see, the for loop has been augmented with an ampersand to execute the `http GET` in the background.  Moreover, a `wait` is added to the end to tell the bash script to wait for all of the child processes to exit.